# Drupal-Content display by username

Tags: drupal

can anyone tell/instruct me on the easiest way to set up Drupal so that a user only sees pages the Administrator deems viewable? For example I need user1 and user2, each with a landing page specific to them that the other cannot see.

I've spent like 6-7 hours on this unsuccessfully, and that's nuts! I've tried v6 and v7, permissions by role, permissions by node, taxonomy access control, etc. Nothing prevents user1 from seeing home page 2 no matter what I do. I figured this would be pretty basic in Drupal.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple ways to do this...

1. Use Organic Groups and assign each user to a different group and then make each page accessible only by specific group
2. Use panels for the home page and set the access permissions for each panel to specify which user roles can view that page (each user needs to be assigned a role)
3. Check the user's roles via a function in template.php (http://www.grasmash.com/node/41 might help you get started) or PHP in page.tpl.php (http://www.bywombats.com/blog/ryan/10-25-2007/checking-if-drupal-user-has-role#comment-948)
4. Try the Content Access module - drupal.org/project/content_access. I've found it works well for limiting or sharing content on a per-user or per-role basis

Comment: Thanks! I have just figured it out. I think I did it with roles and Taxonomy Lite. I think...! Do you know if its possible to set a length of membership - or expiration date for a user?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to always get by with the Content Access module to perform what you are asking.

You could also try it within the code for the page by wrapping it inside a section of code that limits who can see that code, such as;

```
<?php
global $user; 
if($user->roles[3] || $user->roles[4]){ 
    //only for admins or moderators 
}
if($user->roles[0] || $user->roles[1] || $user->roles[DRUPAL_ANONYMOUS_RID] || user_is_anonymous()){
    //everyone else
}       
?>
```

You could also target the allowable sections by user Id, although you would need to know the ID in question first, for example the admin would be `$user->uid[1]`

with regards to length of membership you can get the date the user was created by accessing the created value in the user table which should return a unix timestamp.
 `$usercreated=$user->created;`

To convert this to a more readable date you can use `PHP`'s `strftime()` function as such;
        `$usercreated=date('d M, Y',strftime($user->created));`

To work out the amount of days that a user has been registered for you can always try:
`$days_since=abs(ceil(( strtotime("now") - $user->created )/86400));`

For a listing of all the available user hooks have a look at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--globals.php/global/user/6